# react-native-google-signin -- TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined

Tags: react-native

While importing
`import { GoogleSignin } from 'react-native-google-signin';`

Giving me this error :

> Requiring module "react-native-google-signin/index.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined

Answer (score -1):

In my case using `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` instead of `import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';`  in `GoogleSignin.android.js` file  solved my problem.